# How to separate type of exception from it's message

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

In spring boot application I am handling exception using `@ControllerAdvice`. I am able to handle exception. my JSON message is status, error, exception and path. when I am printing exception string  I am getting exception and and it's message also.

My quation is In exception parameter how to print only type of exception without it's message. because message I am printing in error?

One more Quation is that I am handling all types of exception using only one class i.e. Exception class. For every exception here I am getting `status code` as `500`. Can we set different status code for different type of exception?

Can we pass status code here `throw new NullPointerException("Null values are not allowed");`

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage> handleAllExceptionMethod(Exception ex,WebRequest requset,HttpServletResponse res) {   

        ExceptionMessage exceptionMessageObj = new ExceptionMessage();

        exceptionMessageObj.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        exceptionMessageObj.setError(ex.getLocalizedMessage());     
        exceptionMessageObj.setException(ex.toString());
        exceptionMessageObj.setPath(((ServletWebRequest) requset).getRequest().getServletPath());

        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage>(exceptionMessageObj, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

}

[image]

Comment: I have reservations about throwing NPEs as opposed to using something like bean validation which would give you *very* good error messages and don't require custom exception handler code.  Also, just like you wouldn't want to catch all exceptions, you don't want to handle all exceptions; you want to be specific where you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the name on your message like this:

```
exceptionMessageObj.setException(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

For example:

```
System.out.println(new NoClassDefFoundError().getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

Will return

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine. In my code status is same for every exception. can we change that according to exception type

Comment: I am getting this error `The constructor ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage>(T, MultiValueMap<String,String>, Object) is not visible`

Comment: Sorry, this is another question